# How to see the date when the table was created?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have created a table couple months ago. Is there any way in HIVE that I can see when was the table created?

show table doesn't give the date creation of the table.

Answer (score 26):

Execute the command `desc formatted <database>.<table_name>` on the hive cli. It will show detailed table information similar to

> ## Detailed Table Information
>
> Database:
>   Owner:
>   CreateTime:
>   LastAccessTime:

Comment: Okay. But how do you write it? I tried commands like show table. Example: database: customers, table_name: address. Hive query: show table customers.address.

Comment: How can I save it into a table so I can run query against it. I tried to use it inside a subquery or insert it into a table, but it does not work!

Answer (score 11):

You need to run the following command:

```
describe formatted <your_table_name>;
```

Or if you need this information about a particular partition:

```
describe formatted <your_table_name> partition (<partition_field>=<value>);
```

Comment: We have to provide all the partition columns to get this working. Example: My table has two columns as partition. describe formatted `db_name.table_name` partition (acquisition_date = '2021-10-07', acquisition_hour = '07');

Answer (score 1):

First of all, enable hive support when you create your spark session:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('AppName').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

And then:

```
df_desc = spark.sql('describe formatted <your_table_name>')
df_desc.show()
```