# how to drop hive tables Created 14 of days

Tags: hadoop, hive

Drop hive tables created(no update) since last 14  days , which are created in a `ABC DB` and using `/abc/pqr/xyz/NNN/table_name/` as location . Here `NNN` is a random number ( like 123,125,547 etc)

we can use `DROP TABLE [IF EXISTS] table_name;`

But we need to identify the tables with above constraints

Comment: Maybe this would be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30577239/2026277

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin rights, you can connect to metastore db and search metadata, just a suggestions , not a concrete answer...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the rule

HADOOP TABLES  ARE DIRECTORIES

I have created a shell script to do the below steps.

Step 1. Find all the directories which are not being modified since last 14 days .

Step 2 . Separate real tables and real folders 
2.1execute "desc $dir_name "

2.2 based on return status($？)  redirect $dir_name to two files(one for real tables and other for directories )

Step 3. Drop all tables in real tables file .